# How can add read-only fields programmatically to a template on Android using docusign mobile-android-sdk?

Tags: android, docusignapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxLOR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhQeb.png)How can add read-only fields programmatically to a template on Android using docusign mobile-android-sdk?
I'm using **DSEnvelopeDefaults** and setting **tabValueDefaults** values but I don't know how to set those **tabValueDefaults** read-only.

**QUESTION UPDATE:**

I'm creating tabValueDefaults like this:

```
private fun getTemplateTabData() =
    mapOf<String, Any>(
            "Name $tabKeyName" to user.firstName +" "+ user.lastName,
            "Text $tabKeyTitle0" to user.title,
            "Text $tabKeyTitle1" to user.title,
            "Text $tabKeyStreetAddress" to user.streetAddress
        )
```

Can I make fields "Read only" from here, programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

you can set ‘Ready Only’ property for the tab in template.  You can navigate to Docusign web portal and choose the template. When you placed the tab on the document, on the right side, you will find properties of the tab. There you can select ‘Read only’ property for that tab.
In DSEnvelopeDefaults for tabValueDefaults values, you can provide the tab label and the value, then tab will be rendered as read only during signing.

Comment: I'm creating tabValueDefaults like this: 
`private fun getTemplateTabData() =
        mapOf<String, Any>(
                "Name $tabKeyName" to user.firstName +" "+ user.lastName,
                "Text $tabKeyTitle0" to user.title,
                "Text $tabKeyTitle1" to user.title,
                "Text $tabKeyStreetAddress" to user.streetAddress
            )`
Can I make fields "Read only" from here, programmatically?

Comment: Hi Alexandra, at this time, you can only set tab value based on tab label in DSEnvelopeDefaults. You cannot set 'read only' property dynamically from DSEnvelopeDefaults. You can set 'read only' property from Docusign web as mentioned previously. We will try to provide the option to set 'read only' property programmatically  in future.

Comment: I just check on Docusign web and it is "Read only"

Comment: If you set 'Read-only' in the document for a tab in the template in Docusign web and you are still able to edit those tabs during signing in your mobile application , then please log it as an issue in https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues

Comment: ok, thank you. I created the issue: https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues/3